# Need assistance displaying multiple lines of code from a list in a WPF textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list that pulls data from a feedservice and generates a group of names. I'm trying to place three of these names based on time inside of a text box. I have everything working but i'm having issues with formatting.

```
NextInLine.Text = max3?.Select(x => x?.AgentName).ToList().FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

This will display the name of three people in the format last-first. currently it displays one person name and sometimes will blink and show the other two. I would like all three names to appear on separate lines underneath of each other in the order it is provided in the list.  Can any assist me with formatting. if needed I can add more code on the creation of the list.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="NextInLine" FontFamily="segoe ui"  FontSize="20" Margin="0,205,0,0" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="186" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Loaded="DisplayNumber_Loaded" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NextInLine.Text = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in max3)
    NextInLine.Text += item.AgentName + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: is there anything in my xaml code i have to do to make this work? i attempted it and when i break i see exactly what i want. but when i run the app the text block still only displays the first name.

Comment: Can you please post your XAML?

Comment: Remove Height="30".

Comment: Aggregate would be better than a foreach here as it wont give you the extra new line `max3.Aggregate((r,s)=> r + Environment.NewLine + s)`

Comment: In my opinion a foreach makes the code more readable and one extra line of code is nothing. Shorter doesn't always mean better.

Comment: so i removed the height and the only other problem i'm running in to is that the data is displaying in the incorrect order.  i tried to do the item.agentname.reverse() and nextinline.text.reverse() but neither one of these have the desired result. they are in the correct order before it hits the foreach loop that you suggested. any idea?   basically in line 1 it displays 3, line 2 it displays 2 and line 3 it displays 1 instead of 1 and 1, 2 and 2, 3 and 3

Comment: Try foreach (var item in max3.OrderBy(x => x.AgentName)).

Comment: Well that put them in alphabetical order, but not exactly what i'm looking for. They are being sorted by another field before it enters the foreach loop. any other ideas?

Comment: What field? They will appear in the order that they are sorted in the max3 collection.

Comment: So i ended up doing foreach(var thing in max3.reverse()) and this got me the expected result. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want all three names, you certainly don't want to be calling `.FirstOrDefault()` on the sequence, because that just gives you the first one. And you don't need to call `.ToList()` on it, because you're not keeping the results around.

All you really want to do is select the name of each agent object in the sequence, and join them with newlines. I don't think you need the "null-conditional" `?.` operator either, if I correctly recall how `max3` came to be from your previous questions. `max3` should never be null, though it might have two, one, or even zero items in it. And we selected the items in it (if any) based on their properties, so the items themselves can't be null either.

```
NextInLine.Text = String.Join("\n", max3.Select(x => x.AgentName));
```

Think of it like so:

```
IEnumerable<String> names = max3?.Select(x => x?.AgentName);

String text = String.Join("\n", names);

NextInLine.Text = text;
```